# Insert link/image from sharepoint (assetportalbrowser.aspx) broken when Xlstlistviewwebpart with webid from subsite

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Xlstlistviewwebpart provisioned in a root site and mapped to a list in a subsite programmatically, once I provisioned this web part the assetportalbrowser.aspx start giving me "Value does not fall within the expected range", if I un-provision every thing starts working fine

any idea how can I solve this issue, thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just updating to the last cumulative update solve the problem